# Change color in my website make by jekyll

Tags: css, github, colors

I make a website by jekyll in github.

This is my web and source code

- [My web](https://thorpham.github.io/blog/2017/05/27/code-highlighting/)
- [Source code](https://github.com/ThorPham/ThorPham.github.io)

I want to change color background(of code) from black to white like image below :

[image]

Please help me change this. Thank you

Comment: Please include all relevant information *within the text of the question*, rather than as links, and include your code as a **[Minimum Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**

Answer (score 0):

add this to your style:

```
.highlight {
    background: white !important;
}
.blob-wrapper {
    background: white;
}
pre {
    background: white;
}
table.rouge-table {
    background: white !important;
}
td.code {
    background: white !important;
}
.blob-wrapper.data.type-typescript {
}

.blob-code {
    background: white !important;
}

.blob-num {
    background: white !important;
}
```

also if you want the white text to be black add to every code section color: black;

Comment: Thank you. , in folder _sass my  web  have a lot of file so i don't know where is add your code . Sorry i don't know about web or CSS